# grails access domain objects dynamically

Tags: grails

I am working in grails and
I get my domain class name from a gsp to access an object instance (of a particular id) of this domain class. I am trying the following code. Is this correct?

```
   String id = params['id']
   String className = params['className']

   def instance = className.get(id);
```

Is there any other way to this?

Answer (score 3):

first of all you have to inject the grailsApplication bean in your controller.

```
def grailsApplication
```

after that you can use getClassForName method to retrieve the desired class by name.

```
grailsApplication.getClassForName(className).
```

you have to use the full qualified class name, e.g. my.test.MyClass

Comment: no need for `def grailsApplication` in controllers - the variable is already added to the metaclass

Answer (score 1):

```
def id = params.id
def className = params.'className'

def domainClazz = grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass(className)
def instance = id ? domainClazz.get(id as Long) : null
```

You may:

```
grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass("Book")
```

or

```
grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass("com.yourapp.Book")
```

Comment: note that `grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass("Book")` does not work. So a safer way is to find the class through the grails artefacts.